# Value is not properly passed from parameter to variable when a comma is present (batch file)

Tags: batch-file, parameter-passing

Usage: abc.bat /c 1,2,3

Code:

```
@echo off
echo %1
set variable=%2
echo %variable%
```

Output:

```
/c
1
```

How do I prevent the parameter value from being cut when passed to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Enclose them in double quotes. Call you script using

```
abc.bat /c "1,2,3"
```